# Add a different suffix every two words

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>   DF     
>   Col1      Col2       
>   Sample1    Name1      
>   Sample2    Name2      
>   Sample3    Name3     
>   Sample4    Name4     
>   .......    .....
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>   DF     
>   Col1             Col2       
>   Sample1_case    Name1      
>   Sample2_case1   Name2      
>   Sample3_case    Name3     
>   Sample4_case1   Name4
> ```

In other words I would like to add a different suffix every two words in Col1.

I used the string:

> ```
>    DF = as.data.frame(lapply(DF, paste0, ".case"))
> ```

But I'm not able to add a different suffix every two words. 
Can anyone help me please?

Best

E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recycling:

```
x <- c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4")
y <- c("case", "case1")
paste(x, y, sep="_")
#[1] "sample1_case"  "sample2_case1" "sample3_case"  "sample4_case1"
```

Answer (score 1):

`DF$Col1<-paste(DF$col1,c("case","case1"),sep="_")` should do the trick.

Comment: It only works if the largest vector's length is a multiple of the other's one though.
EDIT : My bad, got confused with vectors multiplication stuff. Ty @Roland

Comment: That's not true. Try it.